# Including bower components in the main Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, bower

In order to include everything I need from each bower component I user a library that does just that (it creates script and link tags for each new component I install and puts them in my main blade):

welcome.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}" style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Work Web App</title>
    <link href="{{mix('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- bower-css:start -->
    <link href="../assets/bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.scss" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bower-css:end -->

</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
<div id="root" class="container-fluid wrapper" style="background: #EDF1F5; height: 100%"></div>
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}" ></script>
<!-- bower-js:start -->
<script src="../assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- bower-js:end -->
</body>
</html>
```

But whenever I try to access my app I get:

```
GET http://*****.test/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://w*****.test/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://*****.test/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://*****.test/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 404 (Not Found)
```

My configuration for my .bowerrc file:

```
{
    "directory": "resources/assets/bower_components",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "bowinst preinstall %",
        "postinstall": "bowinst install %",
        "preuninstall": "bowinst uninstall %"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use? Why you use Bower and not NPM?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel comes with a package.json. All JS deps can be installed by `npm install` and will be downloaded to `node_modules` folder of your root directory.

To built the JS (uglify, minify and some other stuff) you can use Laravel Mix via `npm run dev` (for development), `npm run watch` (for building in dev mode but with a file watcher) or `npm run production` (for production).

The entry point for all this is `resources/assets/js/app.js`. There the `bootstrap.js` file will be imported. (Mind the name here. It has nothing todo with the CSS framework).

Any JS lib you want to include in your application should be required there.

You can find more in-depth information at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix

Comment: I am familiar with laravel mix but I failed to import the css files for bootstrap social into my app.css, for now they are in node_modules after I've installed the library using npm

Comment: What if a js package is only available via bower? like https://github.com/kelvintaywl/dentist.js ? Remember, I am a beginner, and might be missing something.